# Python: isinstance doesn't work properly?

Tags: python-3.x, import, isinstance

I've got a problem with isinstance and I've reduced it to this case.

I have two files.

main.py:

```
import testType
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_class = TestClass()
    testType.test_type(test_class)
```

and testType.py

```
from main import TestClass
def test_type(obj):
    print(type(obj), TestClass)
    print(isinstance(obj, TestClass))
```

And I've got:

```
<class '__main__.TestClass'> <class 'main.TestClass'>
False
```

Why?

How should I fix it?

Comment: Note: Python style normally uses snake_case for variable names, functions and module names, not camelCase. So `test_type` instead of `testType`, and `test_class` instead of `testClass` (which distinguishes it far better from the `TestClass` class than currently).

Comment: @9769953 fixed.

Comment: You have a problem with the circular import, which works, but only imports incomplete modules. The definition of `TestClass` changes along the way when doing this. I will have to leave the details of this to someone else to explain, but the way around it is to put the definition of `TestClass` in a separate module, and import that module in both `main.py` and `testType.py`.

Comment: Thanks, though not entirely: your module name is still testType. But up to you really how much you'd like to conform to standard Python style guidelines.

Comment: It's worked. But looks like I was wrong with reduction...